# Superclass __init__ not recognizing its kwargs

Tags: python, multithreading, subclass, keyword-argument

I'm trying to use the `StoppableThread` class presented as [an answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/325528):

```
import threading

# Technique for creating a thread that can be stopped safely
# Posted by Bluebird75 on StackOverflow
class StoppableThread(threading.Thread):
    """Thread class with a stop() method. The thread itself has to check
    regularly for the stopped() condition."""

    def __init__(self):
        super(StoppableThread, self).__init__()
        self._stop = threading.Event()

    def stop(self):
        self._stop.set()

    def stopped(self):
        return self._stop.isSet()
```

However, if I run something like:

```
st = StoppableThread(target=func)
```

I get:

> TypeError: `__init__()` got an unexpected keyword argument 'target'

Probably an oversight on how this should be used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `StoppableThread` class does not take or pass any additional arguments to `threading.Thread` in the constructor. You need to do something like this instead:

```
class StoppableThread(threading.Thread):
    """Thread class with a stop() method. The thread itself has to check
    regularly for the stopped() condition."""

    def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
        super(threading.Thread,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
        self._stop = threading.Event()
```

This will pass both positional and keyword arguments to the base class.

Answer (score 1):

You are overriding **init** and your **init** doesn't take any arguments. You should add a "target" argument and pass it through to your base class constructor with super or even better allow arbitrary arguments via *args and *kwargs.

I.e.

```
def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
    super(threading.Thread,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)
    self._stop = threading.Event()
```